# Best lossless compression technique for serializing a foot pressure map

Tags: compression, sparse-matrix, image-compression, run-length-encoding

I am working with pressure-sensing of human feet, and I need to transmit frames in realtime over serial.

The typical frame is like below, consisting of a flat background and blobs of non-flat data:

[image]

The speed of transmission is currently a bottleneck due to micro-controller overhead caused by `Serial.send` commands, so the engineer is using [Run Length Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) to compress the image, which seems good due to the flat, continuous background, but we would like to compress it even further.

I tried the "Coordinate List" encoding format (`List<i, j, val>` where `val` > 0), but the size is similar enough to RLE to not make a significant difference.

While researching a bit on SO, people say "don't reinvent the wheel, there are a lot of tried-and-tested compression algorithms for any kind of image", so I wonder what would be the best for the type of image displayed below, considering:

1. Compression performance (since it is to be performed by a micro-controller);
2. Size - since it is to be sent by serial, which is currently a bottleneck (sic).

Other approach would be to use "sparse-matrix" concepts (instead of "image-compression" concepts), and it looks like there is something like [CRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_row_.28CSR.2C_CRS_or_Yale_format.29), or CSR, which I couldn't quite understand how to implement and how to serialize properly, and even less how it would compare with image-compression techniques.

UPDATE:
I created a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/heltonbiker/834cc10a1f81ee38997f4f9070069319) with the data I used to create the image. These were the results of compression methods (one byte per entry):

- plain: (`[n_rows, n_columns, *data]`): **2290** bytes;
- coordinate list: (`[*(i, j, val)]`): **936** bytes;
- run length encoding: (`[*(rowlength, rle-pairs)]`): **846** bytes;
- list of lists: **690** bytes;
- compact list of lists: (see Gist) **498** bytes;

Comment: Since this picture/matrix is quite specific, it might actually make sense to use a custom algorithm. I think the size of the picture is 52x44. Is that correct? How many bits per pixel do you have and what is the current typical size that you get with RLE? Are you looking for a lossless algorithm exclusively? (sorry for putting so many questions in a row)

Comment: RLE only really compresses the large dark blue area, if you used a simple predictor (such as raw-(up+left)/2 aka PNG filter type 3) and then use entropy coding on top of RLE it should be much better. Getting really close to PNG-proper here, you could just use that.

Comment: @Arnauld you guessed right, the size is that. The matrix is 8 bit per pixel. The current typical compressed sizes are described in my update, including a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/heltonbiker/834cc10a1f81ee38997f4f9070069319). I need a lossless compression, that is paramount. Thanks for your interest!

Comment: Did you try deflate? PNG uses deflate after performing a prediction based on 3 pixels around the current pixel.

Comment: @usr I haven't tried yet, because I found it a bit complicated, but for sure I will have to take a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Proposed algorithm

Below is a possible algorithm that is using only simple operations <sup>[1]</sup> with a low memory footprint (no pun intended).

It seems to work reasonably well but, of course, it should be tested on several different data sets in order to have a more precise idea of its efficiency.

1. Divide the matrix into 13x11 blocks of 4x4 pixels
2. For each block:

   - If the block is empty, emit bit '0'
   - If the block is not empty:

     1. emit bit '1'
     2. emit 16-bit bitmask of non-zero pixels in this block
     3. emit 8-bit value representing the minimum value (other than 0) found in this block
     4. if there's only one non-zero pixel, stop here <sup>[2]</sup>
     5. emit 3-bit value representing the number of bits required to encode each non-zero pixel in this block: b = ceil(log<sub>2</sub>(max + 1 - min))
     6. emit non-zero pixel data as N x b bits

It is based on the following observations:

- Many blocks in the matrix are empty
- Non-empty blocks at the frontier of the footprint usually have many empty cells (the 'pressure' / 'no pressure' transition on the sensors is abrupt)

---

<sub>[1] *There's notably no floating point operation. The log2() operation that is used in the description of the algorithm can easily be replaced by simple comparisons against 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ... up to 256.*</sub>

<sub>[2] *This is a minor optimization that will not trigger very often. The decoder will have to detect that there's only one bit set in the bitmask by computing for instance: `(msk & -msk) == msk`.*</sub>

### Block encoding example

Let's consider the following block:

```
 0,  0,  0,  0
12,  0,  0,  0
21, 20,  0,  0
28, 23,  0,  0
```

The bitmask of non-zero pixels is:

```
 0,  0,  0,  0
 1,  0,  0,  0  =  0000100011001100
 1,  1,  0,  0
 1,  1,  0,  0
```

The minimum value is `12` (00001100) and the number of bits required to encode each non-zero pixel is `5` (101), as log<sub>2</sub>(28 + 1 - 12) ~= 4.09.

Finally, let's encode non-zero pixels:

```
  [ 12, 21, 20, 28, 23 ]
- [ 12, 12, 12, 12, 12 ]
------------------------
= [  0,  9,  8, 16, 11 ] = [ 00000, 01001, 01000, 10000, 01011 ]
```

So, the final encoding for this block would be:

```
1 0000100011001100 00001100 101 00000 01001 01000 10000 01011
```

which is 53 bits long (as opposed to 16 * 8 = 128 bits in uncompressed format).

However, the biggest gain comes from empty blocks which are encoded as one single bit. The fact that there are many empty blocks in the matrix is an important assumption in this algorithm.

### Demo

Here is some JS demonstration code working on your original data set:

```js
var nEmpty, nFilled;

function compress(matrix) {
  var x, y, data = '';

  nEmpty = nFilled = 0;
  
  for(y = 0; y < 44; y += 4) {
    for(x = 0; x < 52; x += 4) {
      data += compressBlock(matrix, x, y);
    }
  }
  console.log("Empty blocks: " + nEmpty);
  console.log("Filled blocks: " + nFilled);
  console.log("Average bits per block: " + (data.length / (nEmpty + nFilled)).toFixed(2));
  console.log("Average bits per filled block: " + ((data.length - nEmpty) / nFilled).toFixed(2));
  console.log("Final packed size: " + data.length + " bits --> " + ((data.length + 7) >> 3) + " bytes");
}

function compressBlock(matrix, x, y) {
  var min = 0x100, max = 0, msk = 0, data = [],
      width, v, x0, y0;
  
  for(y0 = 0; y0 < 4; y0++) {
    for(x0 = 0; x0 < 4; x0++) {
      if(v = matrix[y + y0][x + x0]) {
        msk |= 1 << (15 - y0 * 4 - x0);
        data.push(v);
        min = Math.min(min, v);
        max = Math.max(max, v);
      }
    }
  }
  if(msk) {
    nFilled++;
    width = Math.ceil(Math.log(max + 1 - min) / Math.log(2));
    data = data.map(function(v) { return bin(v - min, width); }).join('');
    return '1' + bin(msk, 16) + bin(min, 8) + ((msk & -msk) == msk ? '' : bin(width, 3) + data);
  }
  nEmpty++;
  return '0';
}

function bin(n, sz) {
  var b = n.toString(2);
  return Array(sz + 1 - b.length).join('0') + b;
}

compress([
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0 ],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0 ],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0 ],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0 ],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 10, 12,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0 ],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  7,  0,  0, 10, 12,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 15, 15,  9,  0,  0,  7,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0 ],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  7, 10,  9, 11,  7, 12, 21, 20,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0 ],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 13, 15, 13,  0,  0, 15, 28, 23,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 10,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0 ],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 12,  7,  8,  0,  0,  0,  0, 14,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 14, 12,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0 ],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 11, 10,  0,  0, 11, 19, 12,  9,  8,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 10, 12, 12, 14, 24, 26, 21,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0 ],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  7,  0,  0, 21, 33, 38, 30, 23, 26, 15,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  7, 15, 16, 17, 22, 29, 32, 26, 18,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0 ],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  7,  0, 22, 38, 46, 47, 42, 33, 27, 28,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  7, 14, 18, 18, 23, 28, 32, 31, 23, 12,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0 ],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  7,  7, 17, 31, 52, 54, 55, 48, 36, 34, 32,  9,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  9, 12, 12, 17, 22, 29, 28, 26, 17,  7,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0 ],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 10, 26, 40, 50, 51, 48, 38, 28, 30, 25,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 14, 23, 22, 20, 16, 10,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0 ],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 20, 30, 38, 40, 42, 37, 27, 19, 18, 10,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 11, 15, 13, 12, 10,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0 ],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 13, 24, 27, 28, 30, 32, 26, 13,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  9, 12,  9, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0 ],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 14, 26, 27, 24, 24, 19, 10,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  7,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0 ],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  7, 20, 22, 19, 17, 12,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0 ],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 15, 16, 17, 14,  9,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0 ],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 15, 14, 15, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0 ],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 10, 16, 18, 15,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0 ],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 17, 19, 17,  9,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0 ],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 19, 20, 20,  9,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0 ],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 18, 20, 21, 12,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0 ],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 12, 19, 16, 10,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0 ],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 12, 11,  8,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0 ],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  9,  8,  8,  7,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 10, 12, 12, 10,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0 ],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  8, 10, 10, 13, 13,  8,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  9, 20, 25, 24, 17,  9,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0 ],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 13, 20, 26, 25, 24, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 20, 28, 32, 31, 24, 13,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0 ],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 20, 28, 36, 39, 34, 26,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 11, 29, 36, 39, 37, 30, 18,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0 ],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 22, 31, 43, 50, 58, 39, 15,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 19, 39, 46, 46, 40, 32, 20,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0 ],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 24, 38, 51, 60, 64, 54, 26,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 25, 40, 49, 49, 44, 33, 20,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0 ],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 25, 45, 59, 65, 68, 66, 32,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 21, 40, 46, 46, 42, 31, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0 ],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 22, 44, 56, 66, 70, 61, 32,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 11, 31, 35, 38, 31, 18,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0 ],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 11, 31, 55, 66, 64, 52, 25,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  9, 17, 18, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0 ],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 17, 36, 50, 50, 32, 12,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0 ],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 13, 22, 21, 12,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0 ],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0 ],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0 ],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0 ],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0 ],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0 ],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0 ],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0 ]
]);
```

The final output is **349 bytes** long.

```
Empty blocks: 102
Filled blocks: 41
Average bits per block: 19.50
Average bits per filled block: 65.51
Final packed size: 2788 bits --> 349 bytes
```

Comment: Wow, that was very enlightening. I will not be able to test it till monday at work, but I plan to do it for sure. Also, for what it's worth another valid assumption is that neighboring non-zero data tend to be _smooth_, since the pressure distribution follows a limited-gradient pattern. Usually this lends itself to be represented by "terrain-mode" 3D visualization (or 2.5D like some call it). This knowledge could be used by techniques similar to geographic polyline encoding, where the lower bit-depth _deltas_ from one value to the other are usually represented instead of the values themselves.

Comment: @heltonbiker - I did a few tests that were basically encoding the _deltas_ between the actual value and the prediction `p = round((matrix[y][x - 1] + matrix[y - 1][x]) / 2)`, but they all tend to produce bigger outputs. That said, it is entirely possible that this method simply doesn't 'mix' well with the rest of my algorithm. So, yes: you definitely should explore that path as well.

Comment: Accepting the question because it actually decreased the previously best final size to _one third_ more or less. If I find another option, I post it here as an aditional answer for the record. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Thanks for the follow-up!

Answer (score 1):

I would test JPEG-LS. It is a very fast algorithm and provides state-of-the art lossless compression results for many types of images. In particular, its prediction algorithm will provide results comparable to RLE for the flat regions, and much better results for the foot areas.

Since you are transmitting several frames, and these frames are likely to be very similar, you may want to try to subtract one frame from the next before applying JPEG-LS (you will probably need to remap the pixels to positive integers before using JPEG-LS, though).

If you don't need strictly lossless compression (i.e., if you can tolerate some distortion in the reconstructed images), you can test the near-lossless mode, which bounds the maximum absolute error introduced in any given pixel.

You can find a very good and complete implementation here https://jpeg.org/jpegls/software.html.